# Issues with getting TDA7265 sound amplifier to work with two sound sources

Tags: arduino, circuit-design, sound

I am trying to make a design that makes use of the TDA7265 to amplify sound. I have already had several iterations where I redesigned and ordered a PCB to test out the design, but each seemed to have its own issues. I once got the TDA7265 to work, but only when the sound input wasn't tied to ground, but to some pin on the TDA7265 following some schematic I found somewhere. The problem with that design was that I wanted to have two possible sound sources, sound from an Arduino Due on the same PCB as the sound amplifier (sharing same power source) AND sound from an audio jack input. I have in mind for the audio jack to provide sound like music for most of the time and for the Arduino Due to sometimes produce status messages like "warning, low power."

For this, I made the design seen in the attached schematic, but there is NO sound regardless of the sound source. I have also verified that the Arduino Due produces sound on DAC0 pin. At most you hear some clicking sounds from time to time. The MUTE pin is measured to be 4V. VIN+ is 12V and I have also made sure that the "PLAY" pin is HIGH.

I based my schematic on page 7 of https://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/25084/STMICROELECTRONICS/TDA7265.html so I assume it should at least work when no audio jack is connected (as that would just mean a single sound source.) It won't work unfortunately.

Any idea that can point me in the right direction? I don't have much to any experience with sound amplifiers.

Old schematic from before changes suggested in comments: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tTny1.png

Current schematic:

[image: Updated schematic]

Comment: How did you test it? What power supply rails did you use? What was your input source?

Comment: - I verified that there was sound on DAC0 by connecting GND and DAC0 to my PC speakers input audio jack, sound came from the speakers.
- The power supply is the AC adapter cui inc smi36-12 (12V 3A), I have verified with a power measurement tool that VIN+ to GND is exactly 12V too.

Comment: Wait a minute, I think perhaps the gain is just too low or something. I just put my ear very close to the speaker and I can clearly hear the expected music playing regardless of the source being the PC or the arduino due... its just too low. I suppose I need to find out why that is so.

Comment: I don't know what would be a correct answer for such an open-ended question. But at least you can't just add audio sources together with diodes, and without AC coupling them from each other.

Comment: @Justme I didn't know that, I just imagined the sound input as some alternating voltage going from 0V to some positive voltage, that it would be as easy as just connecting multiple inputs if I didn't expect both sound sources to be audible at the same time.. but thanks, I will read up on that after finding out why the gain is so low.

Comment: C34 is backwards. Try drawing a more sensible schematic. I find it hard to make much sense of. Build the quality in.

Comment: You are right Kartman, fixed it but the sound is still so low that one needs to have the ear up to the speaker to hear anything. About the quality of the schematic, I will attempt to improve it.. practice makes the master. :)

Comment: Do note if the inputs are just wired wrong, the input might never see any audio to amplify. The diodes most likely prevent the circuit from working. Please disconnect the diodes and then try if the audio fed from the audio input connector works properly.

Comment: Hi Justme, I just removed the diodes and attached the audio jack cable from my PC.. it did not end well sadly. I uploaded a youtube video here to demonstrate this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZRN1oKqqiQo

I then tried to connect the arduino due DAC0 directly to the two sound input channels without diodes. This time you could not hear any noise like in the youtube video but the sound is as low as before the diodes were removed.

I will try again to see if I can find any short anywhere.

Comment: According to my oscilloscope, the voltage to the speakers never go below 11.4 volts while the arduino due is playing. Strange.. but guess its to be expected from the behavior I see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using a unipolar 12V power supply. That means you must use the device in single supply mode. The datasheet you are referencing is from 1998. There is a newer datasheet https://www.st.com/en/audio-ics/tda7265.html from 2002 showing how to connect the part in single supply mode (Figure 2).  The basic issue is that you don't have a power supply connection (negative voltage or GND) to the VS- pins of the device. Please modify your circuit to conform to the single supply arrangement shown in figure 2 which will connect VS- to GND. There are a couple of other important components shown in Figure 2 which are required (D1, C2).

As a general guideline, always try to use the datsheet on the device manufacturer's website to ensure you have the most up-to-date information.